# Choosing between "100%" and "cent percent"

Tags: word-choice, subcontinental-english, symbols

I am a non-native English speaker. I am applying for the USA university for management studies. While writing the essay I came across the sentence, "I was 100% confident."

My query:

Is it appropriate to write *100%* or should I write *cent percent*? Does it sound professional?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because “cent” is not English. It is, however, the French word for “hundred” :)   As I don't have edit rights, could someone edit the question and title so that it makes sense?

Comment: @FX_: Yeah, I'll make that edit...

Comment: @Noldorin: I'm pretty sure the asker did mean *cent percent*. The question, "Does it *sound* professional?" also backs up my claim. Majority of speakers would probably not consider this standard usage (and I don't, myself), but see my comment on Robusto's answer.

Comment: By the way, user113, sometimes less is more. It may simply be better from a stylistic point of view to say "I was confident" rather than "I was 100% confident."

Comment: @Jim Oke: Cent means one thing in English; a division of currency/coin. It is plain incorrect to say "cent percent" - perhaps the questioner can clarify what he means.

Comment: @Noldorin: Of course, I know what *cent* means in English :) My point was this: Sometimes it may not be the best idea to edit a question to the degree you did because it does take away a valuable element of the discussion. It is clear that the asker speaks English and pronounces *100%* as *cent percent*. Right or wrong, this would be lost on other users who did not see the original question. It would certainly be nice to know where he or she lives and to find out if *cent percent* is acceptable there.

Comment: And of course, the first *cent* in *cent percent* would have the same meaning as the second *cent*, which is *centum/hundred*. You may want to check out this other link: http://www.englishforums.com/English/IsCentPercentACorrectTerm/wzmqv/post.htm

Comment: @Jimi: You should have said that originally! You just confused me initially hah, but I see your point now. Indeed, "cent percent" seems to be a peculiar term that is unique to Indian English. (It's certainly not used in British English.) Nonetheless, it's probably valid in the dialect relevant to the user, so I've rolled back my edit and added the tag `indian-english`. :)

Comment: Though he seems to be writing for Americans, in which case it's best to use U.S. English...

Comment: @Noldorin: Hah, no worries :) Indeed, he/she is writing an application essay and so should by all means avoid *cent percent*. I wouldn't even use it in any written or formal context, whether Indian, British, Canadian or American. On a second thought, maybe your edit was a good thing. Or, well, maybe it's better as it is now; two sides to every coin. But, please, don't take me too seriously in the future ;) I'm a sort of devil's advocate at times.

Comment: @Jimi: Don't worry, I wasn't insulted... just stubborn if anything. You made a fair point in the end. To be honest, I don't really know Indian English, so I can't common there, though I'd agree it's more likely to be informal.

Comment: @Noldorin: How did you correctly identify this as Indian English - it's very common in India :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would substitute an adjective that means the same thing: totally, completely, absolutely, etc.

As it stands, though, your question makes no sense: "cent percent" is meaningless. Are you asking whether you should spell out "one hundred percent" instead of using numerals? If so, it probably doesn't make a lot of difference. Still, in the context I would use one of the adjectives I suggested here.

Comment: Indeed, *cent percent* is unheard of in the US, but not so in old *BrE* usage and other parts of the English-speaking world. For example: http://www.arabtimesonline.com/NewsDetails/tabid/96/smid/414/ArticleID/156165/reftab/69/t/The-report-is-cent-percent-right-in-light-of-the-expected-deficit-in-the-Kuwaiti-budget/Default.aspx  You could think of it as *one for one/cent for cent*. I hear it's just about standard usage in India/Pakistan.

Comment: @Jimi Okie: True, I have never, ever heard that expression before. Nevertheless, OP is applying to an American university, so avoiding it is probably best.

Comment: Certainly! I only heard of it myself last month and it's not a construction I would use.

Comment: "Cent per cent" is different from "cent percent".  The first means "penny for penny", the second is nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

I would use *100%* when it was an actual measurement, and *one hundred percent* when it's an expression.

> After counting, I saw that 100% of the visitors wore hats. At the time, I was one hundred percent sure of my observation. Later I found out that most were not actually hats, but pets.

Answer (score 2):

Use 100% when you are stating mathematical thought like statistics. Use "one hundred percent" when you are stating non-mathematical thought like a story.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party.

I am from India. I suspect the OP is from India. This is a local usage here. I have heard many people saying "*cent percent*" in place of "*100 %*" but not aware of the origin/cause of this usage.

Comment: I think "cent percent" is an Indo-British convention. It is unheard of in American usage. If colloquially used, we would say "100%.". It is a little casual for writing, so another adjective or no adjective would be better.